# Migrating Nuxt to 2.7: refresh loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on migrating a Nuxt.js project from `Nuxt@1.4` to `2.7`, and after updating the Webpack config as required, etc. I'm now running into the following error.

When I try to access any of the pages on the website, I hit the stock Nuxt loading screen showing bundling progress, which then immediately refreshes ad infinitum. The application never progresses past this screen, and the tab title never changes from `Nuxt.js: Loading app...`.

There are no errors in the console, nor any compile time errors, but when I go to the devtools Network tab, I see a failed (HTTP 500) request to `localhost:3000`, with the following error as response payload:

```
NuxtServerError
render function or template not defined in component: NuxtLoading
```

I looked into NuxtLoading, and the only reference to it I can find is a file in the `.nuxt` folder called `nuxt-loading.vue`, which looks like a regular functioning component. It has a `render()` method, which is implemented as follows:

```
render(h) {
    let el = h(false)
    if (this.show) {
      el = h('div', {
        staticClass: 'nuxt-progress',
        class: {
          'nuxt-progress-notransition': this.skipTimerCount > 0,
          'nuxt-progress-failed': !this.canSucceed
        },
        style: {
          'width': this.percent + '%',
          'left': this.left
        }
      })
    }
    return el
  }
```

**What I've tried**:

- Reinstall `node_modules`;
- `rm -rf .nuxt && yarn dev` (EDIT: and `yarn.lock`);
- Upgrading `element-ui` to latest version.

Thanks in advance for any help. If any more info is needed, please ask.

Comment: Did you remove your `yarn.lock` file? Are you using typescript?

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for the reply. I did remove `yarn.lock`, and I'm not using Typescript.

Comment: Did you remove node_modules? You can also use `yarn outdated` to upgrade dependencies.

Comment: Yeah I removed the `node_modules` folder. `yarn outdated` gives me a couple outdated dependencies; I'll update those and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the outdated packages to their latest versions has not changed anything.

Comment: Ptovide a repro repo

Comment: Hey Aldurund, unfortunately this is all my company's code so I can't easily provide a reproduction. I'll try and see if I can get to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: [Here's a minimal reproduction example](https://github.com/NiekPas/nuxt-repro).

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong configuration  for i18n loader. It should be like this:

```
  config.module.rules.push({
      resourceQuery: /blockType=i18n/,
      type: 'javascript/auto',
      loader: '@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader'

  });
```

Or you can use [nuxt-i18n](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n) module, that will setup this for you using [vueI18nLoader option.](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/options-reference.html#options)

Comment: This seems to at least have progressed my app to some new compilation errors. Thanks! :) I'll mark this as accepted if I run into no further issue.